# How to find points M and N such that AM=CN=BC only with a straight edge and a compass?

Tags: pstricks, pst-eucl

The following code is my attempt to find `M` and `N` such that `AM=CN=BC`.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,pst-calculate}
\begin{document}
\def\x{\pscalculate{6-3.3541}}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-1)(8,8)
\pstGeonode[PosAngle={180,90,0,-90}](1,2){B}(2.5,5){C}(6,2){A}(\x,2){M}
\pspolygon(B)(C)(A)
\pstRotation[PosAngle=90,RotAngle=75.9638]{C}{B}[N]

\psGetDistanceAB[xShift=-8,yShift=4](B)(C){M}
\psGetAngleABC[AngleValue=true,MarkAngleRadius=.5,LabelSep=0.5,%
ShowWedge=false,xShift=-5,yShift=7,arrows=->](B)(C)(A){}

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I am trying not to use `\psGetDistanceAB` and  `\psGetAngleABC`.

## Question

How to get `M` and `N` such that `AM=CN=BC` only with a compass and a straight edge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,pst-calculate,textcomp}
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-1)(8,8)
    \pstTriangle[PosAngle={180,90,0}](1,2){B}(2.5,5){C}(6,2){A}
    \pstInterLC[PointSymbolB=none,PointName=none]{A}{C}{C}{B}{N}{N0}\uput[0](N){N}
    \pstInterLC[PointSymbolB=none,PointName=none,
                Radius=\pstDistCalc{sqrt((2.5-1)^2+(5-2)^2)}]{B}{A}{A}{}{M}{M0}\uput[-90](M){M}
    \psarc[origin={C}]{->}(C){0.5}{(B)}{(N)}\uput{5mm}[-10](C){75.9636\textdegree}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `Radius=\pstDistCalc{sqrt((2.5-1)^2+(5-2)^2)}`  is also possible.

Comment: Why do you replace \pscalculate by \pstDistCalc ?

Comment: It also does the conversion into the internal screen unit, whereas `pscalculate` does only the calculation without taken the current screen unit into account.

Comment: Please explain to me this question. With \psline(A)(B) \psline(C)(D) \psline(E)(F) ... ( can be replaced by another way), why PSTricks does not have the syntax as \tkzDrawSegments(A,B C,D E,F) ? ( Sorry if i have read document uncarefully.)

Comment: until today nobody needs such a command.

Comment: Truly, I want to know the reason why we don't use the syntax as TikZ, PostScript can't ? :-((

Comment: `\psLineSegments(A)(B)(C)(D)(E)(F)` is already possible.

Comment: Oh, yepp, Where can I find the comand \psLineSegments?

Comment: in `pstricks.tex` ( http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/TeXnik/tex/generic/pstricks/) Documentation: http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/TeXnik/doc/generic/pstricks/pst-news19.pdf

Comment: I cannot see it -> new question with example!

Answer (score 4):

The simpler the code the more challenging it becomes.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[PointSymbolB=none,PointNameB=](7,5)
\pstTriangle(1,1){B}(2.5,4){C}(6,1){A}
\pstTranslation[PointName=none,PointSymbol=none]{B}{A}{C}[C']
\pstInterLC[PosAngle=45]{A}{C}{C}{B}{N}{x}
\pstInterLC[PosAngle=-90]{B}{A}{A}{C'}{M}{y}
\pstMarkAngle[MarkAngleRadius=1.1,LabelSep=.8,arrows=->]{B}{C}{A}{\scriptsize$75.96^\circ$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Notes

`PointNameA` and `PointNameB` cannot be assigned `none` but empty. It looks like a bug.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative tikz version:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,bending,arrows.meta,quotes,angles}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=1.2pt},>= Stealth]\footnotesize
\pgfmathsetmacro\BC{sqrt(1.5*1.5+3*3)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\AC{sqrt(3.5*3.5+3*3)}
\draw (1,2)coordinate[dot,label=left:$B$](b)--(2.5,5)coordinate[dot,label=above:$C$](c)--(6,2)coordinate[dot,label=right:$A$](a)--cycle;
\node at ([xshift=-\BC cm]a) [dot,label=below:$M$] {};
\node at ($(c)!\BC/\AC!(a)$) [dot,label=right:$N$] {};
\pic["75.96\textdegree",draw,->,angle eccentricity=.7,angle radius=1cm] {angle=b--c--a};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

A version in which you do not have to compute anything yourself. All distances and angles can be very conveniently computed with Ti*k*Z. In more detail, the following code computes the distance between `B` and `C` (`\n1`) as well as the "slopes" of all the edges, and then uses polar coordinates to set `M` `\n1` away from `A` in `B` direction and `N` `\n1` away from `C` in `A` direction. The angle at `B` is also computed by `tikz` and inserted via `\pgfmathprintnumber` which allows you to specify the number of digits and so on, if needed.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (1,2) coordinate[label=below:$B$] (B) -- 
(2.5,5) coordinate[label=above:$C$] (C) -- 
(6,2) coordinate[label=right:$A$] (A) -- cycle;
\path let \p1=($(B)-(C)$),\p2=($(B)-(A)$),\p3=($(A)-(C)$),
\n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)},\n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)},\n3={atan2(\y3,\x3)},
\n4={\n3-atan2(\y1,\x1)} in 
($(A)+(\n2:\n1)$) coordinate[label=below:$M$] (M)
($(C)+(\n3:\n1)$) coordinate[label=above right:$N$] (N)
pic["$\pgfmathparse{\n4}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}^\circ$",draw,-latex,angle
eccentricity=1.3,angle radius=1cm] 
{angle=B--C--A};
\foreach \X in {A,B,C,M,N}
{\fill (\X) circle (1pt);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]